# Deploying Django to Production (Not on Heroku/PythonAnywhere)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i currently have completed my Django Project and am ready to launch it.Its my first time launching so I'm asking if anyone has a checklist of what is required to be changed before you launch it to production.

`After launching it, do you need to keep your laptop switched on at all times to runserver? Or is there a way to someone else's server to run it, and if I use IAAS from someone else, would I be able to makechanges/ access the admin panel anytime i want?

- i need to change DEBUG from true to false

-My static CDN and email login confirmations, how will they be stored and how will i be able to access them?

-The settings secret key, will the settings.py file be widely available to the public for everyone to see? Or will it be hidden. If hidden, how can i hide it. Also same for the stripe key.

-Requirements.txt, how do I "import" all the codes to the "server" to make sure that they all work?

-What are all the files to be hidden from the public and how can I hide them?

- Is there anymore changes that I need to make?

Comment: [Checkout this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment). A lot of your questions will be answered from reading this.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

Comment: thank you for the resource recommendations!!!